# Date input taken from userform combobox cannot be matched with dates in mm/dd/yyyy fomat in arange i

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following combobox controls in my userform :-
`MonthBox`, `YearBox` and `DateOfLeave`.
I want to match the dates entered in
mm/dd/yyyy format (with DateSerial function) from `MonthBox` and `YearBox` in a range starting from D5 cell with dates taken from `DateOfLeave` as simple number like 1 2 3 .....with a for next loop.
The codes I entered are:-

```
Dim count_col as integer
For j = 4 to last_entered_col
    If DateOfLeave.Value = 
        Cells(5,j).Value Then
        count_col = j
        Exit for
Next j
```

Now this match is not taking place which is evident from `count_col` always remaining 0
How to sort this out ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Dim count_col As Integer
Dim counter   As Integer

For counter = 4 To last_entered_col
    If DateDiff("d", DateSerial(YearBox, MonthBox, Cells(5, counter).Value), DateOfLeave.Value) = 0 Then
        count_col = counter
        Exit for
    End If
Next
```